# Scipy sparse-matrix factorization without memory reallocation

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, linear-algebra

I am working on a nonlinear finite element solver in Python, using `scipy` sparse matrices. The solver generates a tangent stiffness matrix named `KT` (`scipy.sparse.csc_matrix()`) which is updated several times during runtime - but does not change in shape and a load vector `F`. Then the iterative displacements `deltaU` are calculated as `KT * deltaU = F`.

The (schematic) current proceeding is:

```py
import scipy.sparse as sps
while error > max_error:
    KT = updateKT()
    F = updateF()
    solveRHS = sps.linalg.factorized(KT)
    deltaU = solveRHS(F)
    error = calculate_error(F,deltaU,...)
```

If I simulate quite large models, the factorization costs a few gigabytes of memory. So, after the first iteration, during the factorization of `KT11` the double memory is needed (memory of solveRHS + spslinalg.factorized(self.KT)).

By deleting `solveRHS` after having solved the SLAE,

```py
import scipy.sparse as sps
while error > max_error:
    KT = updateKT()
    F = updateF()
    solveRHS = sps.linalg.factorized(KT)
    deltaU = solveRHS(F)
    del solveRHS
    error = calculate_error(F,deltaU,...)
```

I can reduce the memory footprint - but at the cost of allocating the memory for the factorization in each iteration - which costs a few seconds per iteration.

*Is there a possibility, that the "new" solver function is directy written into `solveRHS`, without having to reallocate memory?*

Comment: Are you saying that the iteration changes the `self.KT.data` attribute, but nothing else?  Is `solveRHS` also a sparse matrix?  With the same sparsity structure each iteration?  Can you deduce how the `data` of one maps on to the other?

Comment: Yes, only the data part of `KT`changes. The structure remains the same, all the time. According to the [_scipy_ docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.factorized.html), `solveRHS = sps.linalg.factorized(KT)` is a _function for solving a sparse linear system, with KT pre-factorized_.

Answer (score 0):

According to sps.linalg.factorized source https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.16.1/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/linsolve.py#L318, factorized call splu(A).solve using functional programming. So you can input the parameter into sps.linalg.factorized(KT) like a function.

```
import scipy.sparse as sps
while error > max_error:
    KT = updateKT()
    F = updateF()
    deltaU = sps.linalg.factorized(KT)(F)
    error = calculate_error(F,deltaU,...)
```

Other solution, you can implement your own LU factorization with pivoting so that you can optimize code more efficient, but you have more risks as well.

Hope this helps! Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but as I need the factorized matrix at another point for a second time (arc-lenghth solvers), this is sadly no option for me.

Comment: You can use list comprehension like this, for example: G is another matrix that is used for the second time: results = [sps.linalg.factorized(KT)(mat) for mat in [F, G]]

Comment: Actually, this will shorten the code but you have to double calculating the factorized matrix again...